# pandas filling date gaps and overwrite with function

Tags: pandas, gaps-in-data

I have a big data frame with 2 groups: score and day.
Is there a simple possibility with pandas tools to fill the gaps and the missing scores with the average (alternative ewma etc..) of the values before.

First of all I group overwrite the scores by grouping and later stack the 
modified grouped df's together.

```python
 dfg = df.groupby(['g1','g2'])
 for name , group in dfg:
    print group
    break
```

```all
 ix               g1           g2   score      day
 4                19           24    4.150513  2014-02-12
 5                19           24    6.986235  2014-02-13
 6                19           24    9.634231  2014-02-14
 7                19           24    1.818548  2014-02-15
 8                19           24    1.699897  2014-03-02
 9                19           24    2.128781  2014-03-25
 10               19           24    1.720297  2014-03-26
 14               19           24    2.079877  2014-03-30
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? If the whole point is an econometric regression, you are not adding any more information to your data. Any method-of-moments estimator should handle those gaps better than your manual interpolation everwill.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it's business as usual and the analytical meaningfulness becomes secondary :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but looking at the manual gave me the following as idea as a starting point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2011-01-01', '1'], ['2011-01-03', '2']], columns=['day', 'score']).set_index('day')
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=12, freq='d')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(columns=['day'], index=rng))

# now, for those that we actually have data, put it in:
df2['score'] = df['score']
```

The final result then:

```
               score
2011-01-01     1
2011-01-02   NaN
2011-01-03     2
2011-01-04   NaN
2011-01-05   NaN
2011-01-06   NaN
2011-01-07   NaN
2011-01-08   NaN
2011-01-09   NaN
2011-01-10   NaN
2011-01-11   NaN
2011-01-12   NaN
```

Now, you can apply interpolation methods on the `NaN` values as described in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html).

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. Got an error for                  df.index = df.index.to_datetime
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable   Version:
0.13.0

Comment: That's because the brackets magically went missing. Fixed the line :)